# How to generate a groovy.lang.Closure from xml template in gradle/groovy script

Tags: gradle, groovy, pom.xml

I need to generate pom in a gradle project.

It is like this

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

install {
  repositories.mavenInstaller {
    pom.withXml(pomConfig(project.version))
...
```

Function `pomConfig(project.version)` should load a pom template from disk then substitute `${project.version}` and returns a groovy.lang.Closure instance.

Function pom.withXml would not accept a groovy util node created by`def xml = new XmlParser().parse("pom-template.xml")`.

I don't know how to create a groovy.lang.Closure instance by xml.

Comment: [MavenPom.html#withXml(groovy.lang.Closure)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/maven/MavenPom.html#withXml(groovy.lang.Closure)) : Adds a closure to be called when the POM XML has been created. you'll get reference to created pom in this closure and you can modify it. check this: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/maven-publish/pomCustomization/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

```
pom.withXml { pomConfig(project.version) }
```

https://github.com/xvik/gradle-pom-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/ru/vyarus/gradle/plugin/pom/PomConvention.groovy#L33